# Installing java,tomcat ,eclipse and maven in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am new to java and to get my project working I need eclipse, java, tomcat and maven. I am using Ubuntu. Is there any particular order for installations? Is there any place I can get a detailed read about it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793071/how-to-start-using-and-developing-on-ubuntu-linux) discussion might be helpful

Comment: Install Java, then try to install Eclipse for Java EE https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen2 (This will install maven, tomcat out-of-the-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install JDK (Java Development Kit): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

To install JRE (Java Runtime Environment):  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

To install Eclipse: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

To install Tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi

You need to install JRE first because Eclipse is built with Java. Select the appropriate pacgakes to the Ubuntu OS in the download pages.

Maven is included in the Eclipse EE environment.